# Active code for login user by time in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want a code to be sent to the user and that code can be used for 3 minutes to log in the user so that the user cannot request a code in these 3 minutes.

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

David's advice is very good, you should write the code first and ask questions when you encounter problems.

**Regarding your needs, I can provide you with some ideas.**

1. First you need to know that when the browser client connects with the asp.net core webserver, the session ID is generated when the connection is established.
2. We can customize the code, codeState in session, to determine whether the user who established the connection has logged in.

   ```
   code            string type: 0123 or Az02

   codeState       null ->  not generated
                   -1   ->  expired
                   0    ->  generated but un-use
                   1    ->  used
   ```

   ---

   ```
   if(codeState=null){
       code = generate_code();
       HttpContext.Session.SetString("code",code);
   }
   if(codeState == -1){
       msg = "The code has expired, pls click the button to generate a new code";
   }
   if(codeState== 0){
       msg = "The code has generated";
       code = HttpContext.Session.GetString("code");
   }
   if(codeState== 1){
       msg = "The code has used";
   }
   ```